# Biztalk : can a message select an orchestration to be processed by?

Tags: biztalk

Can a message select between an 'older' or 'latest' version of the orchestration he'd like to be prosessed by ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about the version fo the DLL in the GAC, I don't think this is possible.  But if you maintain two seperate Orchestrations, you can use a promoted property to route the message to the appropriate orchestration.  If it's more complicated than that, you can have a single receiving orchestration for themessage type and it can call the appropriate orchestration based on whatever criteria you can code into it.  This is still the send port groups deciding which messages they want to run.  Another approach would be Dynamic Send Ports.  This really gives you the freedom to move direction of the message into the orchestration/app itself.

The Microsoft ESB 2.0 Guidance has some extensive thoughts on Itineraries which as I understand it, is the concept of the message containing specific processing steps on board.  I am still digesting this, but it may be something to look at.